# In java is the public attribute in base class invisible in derived class?

Tags: java, maven

```
class base {
    public <type> a;

}

class derived extends base {
     ...
     public void dMethod() {
         a.method();
     }
     ...
}
```

The snippt comes from a package A I use in my project.  `derived` shall see the `a` in base , so it could use it.

But when I run `mvn clean install` to package my project, it complains that it can't find 
symbol a in class derived(I have added the package A in dependency).

What's wrong with it?

**Edit:**

I use that code in my project like this:

```
class my {
    derived d = new derived();
    d.a.method();
     ...
}
```

It works fine in eclipse, but when I package it, it complains.
And the `method()` does have `public` modifier.

Comment: larmbr, first of all, try using an IDE such as Eclipse or IntelliJ. Maven is not the problem, but rather your code is not valid Java code. Try following a tutorial on java to learn the syntax.

Comment: Does your classes have default access modifier? Means have you forgotten to specify modifier in question or in classes.

Comment: Are you having Base class in a different jar project or same jar project but different package?

Comment: From what I'm seeing, your code should work fine. So I'm guessing you aren't showing us something.

Comment: "It complains that it can't find symbol a" Are you sure? It would be comprehensible if it said it could not find symbol `method` in `base`, which would mean that `method()` isn't accessible to `derived`.

Answer (score 2):

**A public attribute or method is visible everywhere**.

Since `a` is public, you can access it from a derived class (or any other class in your code).

However, even if `a` is public, that does not makes its methods public. In your case if you have a problem calling `a.method()`, it's because `method` is not visible in your context (it could be private, protected or having a package visibility).

The solution would be to check the method `a.method()` and can change it to public if you can. Or maybe the object `a` is meant to be used differently.

Answer (score 0):

method() should have a public (or in this case protected would also be ok) identifier...
having public on identifier on 'a' does not make all its fields and methods public.